# HtmlAgilityPack Issue in reading html

Tags: c#, html, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am reading websites in C# and get contents as string....there are some sites which do not have well formed html structure.

I am using HtmlAgilityPack which give me issue in that case.

Can you people suggest me what to use so that it can read whole string and i can get useful informations?

Here is my code

```
 htmlDoc.LoadHtml(s);
  if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors != null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
```

Why this IF Condition is true for my case

Comment: I believe that `ParseErrors` collection can answer your question

Comment: I think, your HTML is invalid. Can you provide the value of s?

Comment: @speti43  yes i know my html is not valid,that is what i mentioned in my question....i can not correct html as it comes directly from webpages..what to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the error you're getting? Is it throwing an exception or are you just wanting to see the error? Hard to tell what your actual question is.

You can see the markup errors in the HTML by using the `HtmlDoc.ParseErrors` property and iterate though them. This will give you the line number, code and type of error.

You can see more info about this property here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367455/235644

**Edit**

Ok so you've updated your question since my reply. You can see the specific error that's returning true in your IF statement by looping through the `.ParseErrors` are described above.

**Second Edit**

You can loop though the errors like so:

```
 foreach (var error in htmlDoc.ParseErrors)
 {
      Debug.WriteLine(error.Line);
      Debug.WriteLine(error.Reason);
 }
```

Comment: ParseErrors.count give me 59 so it comes in IF condition.when i use "htmlDoc.ParseErrors.ToString();" it give me this error..."System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlParseError]"

Comment: You cannot just call `.ToString()` on a List<>. You need to loop through each error.

Comment: @Methew - I've updated my answer to demo how to loop though the `ParseErrors`

Comment: I check "htmlDoc.ParseErrors" it tell me _code="EndTagNotRequired" and _reason End Tag </option> is not required...

Comment: Ok - so that answers your question do it not?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the bug in your HTML, and after it is valid you can go on.
Here is the same problem:
[Invalid HTML in AgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447461/htmlagilitypack-invalid-markup)

Comment: I check "htmlDoc.ParseErrors" it tell me _code="EndTagNotRequired" and _reason End Tag </option> is not required...

Comment: @speti - I gathered it's not his HTML as he state he's `reading websites`. I assume a spider of some sort.

Comment: @DaveHogan: is 100% right...i have a spider so what to do now?

Comment: I've not said to correct the website html, just correct the loaded html in the memory, but he can correct a specific error, so it's not a permanent solution.

Comment: i use "HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");"..now it give me En Tag </input> not required...

Answer (score 0):

If your html is external and you can't fix it, you can first run it through a cleanup preprocessor, then parse it with `HtmlAgilityPack`.

This will attempt to fix as many issues as possible automatically before `HtmlAgilityPack` gets to see it. The most popular HTML cleanup tool is Tidy. See the .NET version here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/